# Functions that are strictly convex, coercive, continuously twice differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $F:[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

(a) $F(t,\cdot)$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ (b) $F(t,\cdot)$ is strictly convex uniformly in $t \in [0,T]$ (c) $F(t,\cdot)$ is coericve (d) $F$ and $\nabla_uF$ are locally Lipschitz.

Then what are the functions that satisfy all the above properties? For example

(a) $F(t,x(t))= \|x(t)\|^2$ or $\|x(t)\|^4$ and so on, the even powers and theirs linear combinations. (b) something like $F(t,x(t))= \|x(t)-a\|^2$  and the even powers, but $F(t,x(t))$ cannot be something like $\|x(t)\|$ and the odd powers.

I'm trying to find some more candidate functions which satisfied all the properties (a)-(d), are there any other possibilities? And if I want to restrict the functions $F$ to be like $\|x(t)\|^2$ and the even powers, do I need any more hypothesis?

Comment: $F(t,x)=\|x\|^p$ satisfies the conditions for all  $p>1$. Try to look for functions $F$ independent of $t$. A function not satisfying $b$ would be $F(t,x) = t \|x\|^2$.

Comment: @daw : Yes I tried to look for F's independent of $t$ and came up with those examples; so the functions like $||x-x_0||^p$ will also work right? and what about the combinations like $\|x\|^p+ \|x\|^q$